# Entity Framework: Compare dates through Expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, expression

I am building an expression Tree using both Expressions and the LinqKit PredicateBuilder to search for data. 
I am having problems trying to compare Dates on the datefield only.

The .Date field can't be used as the Entity Framework doesn't support it. I can't use the DbFunctions.TruncateTime functions as I am building the Expression first.

Does anyone know what I can do in this case?

Some code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Builds a conditional Expression based upon the comparison type passed
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The class the conditional expression is for</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="DataType">The type of data to be compared upon</typeparam>
    /// <param name="selector">Expression to retrieve the Field to compare on</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value to compare to</param>
    /// <param name="comparison">The comparison type to use</param>
    /// <param name="expressions">Any additional expression to add (using AND) to this one)</param>
    /// <returns>The expression requested</returns>
    private Expression<Func<T, bool>> BuildCondition<T, DataType>(Expression<Func<T, DataType>> selector, DataType value, Comparison comparison, params Expression<Func<T, bool>>[] expressions)
    {            
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> result = null;
        switch (comparison)
        {
            case Comparison.Equals:
            default:
                result = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.Equal(selector.Body, Expression.Constant(value)), selector.Parameters);
                break;
            case Comparison.NotEquals:
                result = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.NotEqual(selector.Body, Expression.Constant(value)), selector.Parameters);
                break;
            case Comparison.SmallerThan:
                result = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.LessThan(selector.Body, Expression.Constant(value)), selector.Parameters);
                break;
            case Comparison.SmallerOrEquals:
                result = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.LessThanOrEqual(selector.Body, Expression.Constant(value)), selector.Parameters);
                break;
            case Comparison.GreaterThan:
                result = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.GreaterThan(selector.Body, Expression.Constant(value)), selector.Parameters);
                break;
            case Comparison.GreaterOrEquals:
                result = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(selector.Body, Expression.Constant(value)), selector.Parameters);
                break;
        }

        if (expressions != null)
        {
            foreach (var exp in expressions) result = result.And(exp);
        }

        return result.Expand();
    }
```

Usage

```
var pr = PredicateBuilder.False<QuestionnaireUserResponseGroup>();
pr = pr.And(BuildCondition<QuestionnaireUserResponseGroup, string>((r => r.DateTimeCompleted), searchCondition.Value, searchCondition.Comparison));
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If you are using SQL Server you can use the [SQLFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions(v=vs.110).aspx) class

Comment: You can't use that as you get the error This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities